# House of Santa Claus

Tags: graphs-and-networks, combinatorics

The house of Santa Claus is an old German drawing game for small children.
You have to draw a house in one line.  
You must not lift your pencil while drawing. $\color{red}{\text{You must not repeat a line.}}$

A possible solution for drawing such a house is:

[image]

The drawings sequence is here: 1->2->4->1->3->4->5->3->2

How can one find out all existing drawing sequences using Mathematica?

**UPDATE**:

Each starting position should be possible and the last line should end at the starting position.

Comment: Just a short comment on terminology: in Germany this house is not owned by Santa Claus (Weihnachtsmann) but by another, admittedly very similar looking, man called Nikolaus, which comes in the night to the 6th of December into the home of people and fills the shoes of good kids with sweets, under the condition that the shoes have been polished to shine bright.

Comment: Michael Trott has this as an example in his "Guidebook Programming", there a rule-based approach to determine all possibilities to draw the "house" in (all) different ways

Comment: Using the standard function FindEulerianCycle[] I have now found all 44 Eulerian paths, hereby confirming my previous 12 solutions which start on the "floor" egde. See full solution.

Comment: @mrz: the sentence in your update "Each starting position should be possible and the last line should end at the starting position." contains  two errors (1) the starting position must be an odd vertex (2) there is no closed path going through all edges once. See my full solution for details.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Full solution**

*Outline of solution*

The OP asks for a path which contais all vertices and all egdes but must not go through any egde twice. 
This kind of path is called Eulerian path (EP). It was first discussed by Leonhard Euler in his famous "Königsberger Brückenproblem".

Euler also proved that for a closed Eulerian path, called Eulerian circle (EC), to exist, all vertices must have an even number of edges (even vertex), and furthermore than an open EP exist if and only if there are exactly two vertices with an odd number of edges (odd vertex), all others must  be even. The path then has to start at one of the odd vertices and end on the other.

In our house the two odd vertices are 1 and 2 on the floor of the house.

In order to find all EP we shall use the standard function `FindEulerianCycle[].` But as our house has no EC we apply a trick, we add an auxiliary vertex no. 6 which is connected to 1 and 2. Then we let Mathematica calculate the ECs, and finally delete the connections {1,6} and {6,2} from the results.

We find 44 Eulerian paths.

*Solution*

The undirected edges of the auxiliary graph are

```
edges = {{1, 6}, {6, 2}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}, {1, 4}, {2, 3}, {2, 4}, {3, 4}, {3, 
   5}, {4, 5}}; (* undirected edges *)
```

Nor we find all ECs

```
ec = FindEulerianCycle[edges, All];
Short[%] (* not displayed here *)

Length[ec]

Out[128]= 44
```

The removal of the two auxiliary edges is easily done here by dropping the first two entries

```
ep1 = Drop[#, 2] & /@ ec;
Short[%] (* not displayed here *)
```

In List form this becomes

```
ep2 = (# /. UndirectedEdge -> List & /@ #) & /@ ep1;
Short[%] (* not displayed here *)
```

In vertex form the paths are

```
ep3 = Join[(#[[1]] &) /@ #, {#[[-1, 2]]}] & /@ ep2;
Short[%] (* not displayed here *)
```

Hence we have found

```
{Length[ep3], Length[Union[ep3]]}

(* Out[149]= {44, 44} *)
```

different Eulerian paths.

These can be attributed to one of the the three starting sequences {2->1},{2->3}, and {2->4}:

```
ep21 = Select[ep3, #[[2]] == 1 &]

(* Out[151]= {
{2, 1, 4, 5, 3, 4, 2, 3, 1}, {2, 1, 4, 5, 3, 2, 4, 3, 1}, 
{2, 1, 4, 3, 5, 4, 2, 3, 1}, {2, 1, 4, 3, 2, 4, 5, 3, 1}, 
{2, 1, 4, 2, 3, 5, 4, 3, 1}, {2, 1, 4, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 1}, 
{2, 1, 3, 5, 4, 3, 2, 4, 1}, {2, 1, 3, 5, 4, 2, 3, 4, 1}, 
{2, 1, 3, 4, 5, 3, 2, 4, 1}, {2, 1, 3, 4, 2, 3, 5, 4, 1}, 
{2, 1, 3, 2, 4, 5, 3, 4, 1}, {2, 1, 3, 2, 4, 3, 5, 4, 1}}
*)

Length[ep21]

(* Out[156]= 12 *)
```

This confirms my previous manual finding.

```
ep23 = Select[ep3, #[[2]] == 3 &]

(* Out[153]= {
{2, 3, 5, 4, 3, 1, 4, 2, 1}, {2, 3, 5, 4, 3, 1, 2, 4, 1}, 
{2, 3, 5, 4, 2, 1, 4, 3, 1}, {2, 3, 5, 4, 2, 1, 3, 4, 1}, 
{2, 3, 5, 4, 1, 3, 4, 2, 1}, {2, 3, 5, 4, 1, 2, 4, 3, 1}, 
{2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 1, 4, 2, 1}, {2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 1, 2, 4, 1}, 
{2, 3, 4, 2, 1, 4, 5, 3, 1}, {2, 3, 4, 2, 1, 3, 5, 4, 1}, 
{2, 3, 4, 1, 3, 5, 4, 2, 1}, {2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 4, 5, 3, 1}, 
{2, 3, 1, 4, 5, 3, 4, 2, 1}, {2, 3, 1, 4, 3, 5, 4, 2, 1}, 
{2, 3, 1, 2, 4, 5, 3, 4, 1}, {2, 3, 1, 2, 4, 3, 5, 4, 1}}
*)

Length[ep23]

(* Out[154]= 16 *)

ep24 = Select[ep3, #[[2]] == 4 &]

(* Out[152]= {
{2, 4, 5, 3, 4, 1, 3, 2, 1}, {2, 4, 5, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 1}, 
{2, 4, 5, 3, 2, 1, 4, 3, 1}, {2, 4, 5, 3, 2, 1, 3, 4, 1}, 
{2, 4, 5, 3, 1, 4, 3, 2, 1}, {2, 4, 5, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1}, 
{2, 4, 3, 5, 4, 1, 3, 2, 1}, {2, 4, 3, 5, 4, 1, 2, 3, 1}, 
{2, 4, 3, 2, 1, 4, 5, 3, 1}, {2, 4, 3, 2, 1, 3, 5, 4, 1}, 
{2, 4, 3, 1, 4, 5, 3, 2, 1}, {2, 4, 3, 1, 2, 3, 5, 4, 1}, 
{2, 4, 1, 3, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1}, {2, 4, 1, 3, 4, 5, 3, 2, 1}, 
{2, 4, 1, 2, 3, 5, 4, 3, 1}, {2, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 1}}
*)

Length[ep24]

(* Out[155]= 16 *)
```

Graphically these are

```
pnts = {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}, {1/2, 1 + Sqrt[3]/2}};

GraphicsGrid[
 Partition[Table[
   Show[Graphics[
     Line[Table[{Random[]/5, Random[]/5} + pnts[[ep21[[k, i]]]], {i, 1, 
        9}]]]], {k, 1, Length[ep21]}], 6], ImageSize -> 800]
```

[image]

```
GraphicsGrid[
 Partition[
  Table[Show[
    Graphics[
     Line[Table[{Random[]/5, Random[]/5} + pnts[[ep23[[k, i]]]], {i, 
        1, 9}]]]], {k, 1, Length[ep23]}], 8], ImageSize -> 800]
```

[image]

```
GraphicsGrid[
 Partition[
  Table[Show[
    Graphics[
     Line[Table[{Random[]/5, Random[]/5} + pnts[[ep24[[k, i]]]], {i, 
        1, 9}]]]], {k, 1, Length[ep24]}], 8], ImageSize -> 800]
```

[image]

**Original solution**

I found manually that there are the following 12 tours (sequences of vertices) beginning with 1->2

```
tv = {{1, 2, 3, 1, 4, 3, 5, 4, 2}, {1, 2, 3, 1, 4, 5, 3, 4, 2}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 
    1, 3, 5, 4, 2}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 1, 4, 2}, {1, 2, 3, 5, 4, 1, 3, 4, 
    2}, {1, 2, 3, 5, 4, 3, 1, 4, 2}, {1, 2, 4, 1, 3, 4, 5, 3, 2}, {1, 2, 4, 1,
     3, 5, 4, 3, 2}, {1, 2, 4, 3, 1, 4, 5, 3, 2}, {1, 2, 4, 3, 5, 4, 1, 3, 
    2}, {1, 2, 4, 5, 3, 1, 4, 3, 2}, {1, 2, 4, 5, 3, 4, 1, 3, 2}};
```

The evoluton of the drawings can be followed in this picture

```
pnts = {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}, {1/2, 1 + Sqrt[3]/2}};
GraphicsGrid[
 Partition[Table[
   Show[Graphics[
     Line[Table[{Random[]/5, Random[]/5} + pnts[[tv[[k, i]]]], {i, 1, 
        9}]]]], {k, 1, 12}], 6], ImageSize -> 800]
```

[image]

Comment: Funny way of visualizing the paths :)

Comment: This is very nice ...

Answer (score 20):

This is of course the [Chinese postman problem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChinesePostmanProblem.html), which is solved by the function `FindPostmanTour[]`. First, represent the edges of the directed graph:

```
edges = {1 -> 2, 1 -> 3, 2 -> 4, 3 -> 2, 3 -> 4, 4 -> 1, 4 -> 5, 5 -> 3};
house = Graph[edges,
              VertexCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}, {1/2, 1 + Sqrt[3]/2}},
              EdgeStyle -> Directive[Thick, Black],
              VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center], VertexSize -> Small, 
              VertexStyle -> Directive[FaceForm[None], EdgeForm[Black]]];
```

[image: house]

Find all tours:

```
tours = FindPostmanTour[edges, All]
   {{1 -> 2, 2 -> 4, 4 -> 5, 5 -> 3, 3 -> 4, 4 -> 1, 1 -> 3, 3 -> 2, 2 -> 4, 4 -> 1},
    {1 -> 2, 2 -> 4, 4 -> 5, 5 -> 3, 3 -> 4, 4 -> 1, 1 -> 3, 3 -> 2, 2 -> 4, 4 -> 1},
    {1 -> 2, 2 -> 4, 4 -> 5, 5 -> 3, 3 -> 2, 2 -> 4, 4 -> 1, 1 -> 3, 3 -> 4, 4 -> 1},
    {1 -> 2, 2 -> 4, 4 -> 5, 5 -> 3, 3 -> 2, 2 -> 4, 4 -> 1, 1 -> 3, 3 -> 4, 4 -> 1},
    {1 -> 2, 2 -> 4, 4 -> 1, 1 -> 3, 3 -> 4, 4 -> 5, 5 -> 3, 3 -> 2, 2 -> 4, 4 -> 1},
    {1 -> 2, 2 -> 4, 4 -> 1, 1 -> 3, 3 -> 2, 2 -> 4, 4 -> 5, 5 -> 3, 3 -> 4, 4 -> 1},
    {1 -> 2, 2 -> 4, 4 -> 1, 1 -> 3, 3 -> 4, 4 -> 5, 5 -> 3, 3 -> 2, 2 -> 4, 4 -> 1},
    {1 -> 2, 2 -> 4, 4 -> 1, 1 -> 3, 3 -> 2, 2 -> 4, 4 -> 5, 5 -> 3, 3 -> 4, 4 -> 1},
    {1 -> 2, 2 -> 4, 4 -> 5, 5 -> 3, 3 -> 4, 4 -> 1, 1 -> 3, 3 -> 2, 2 -> 4, 4 -> 1},
    {1 -> 2, 2 -> 4, 4 -> 5, 5 -> 3, 3 -> 4, 4 -> 1, 1 -> 3, 3 -> 2, 2 -> 4, 4 -> 1},
    {1 -> 2, 2 -> 4, 4 -> 5, 5 -> 3, 3 -> 2, 2 -> 4, 4 -> 1, 1 -> 3, 3 -> 4, 4 -> 1},
    {1 -> 2, 2 -> 4, 4 -> 5, 5 -> 3, 3 -> 2, 2 -> 4, 4 -> 1, 1 -> 3, 3 -> 4, 4 -> 1},
    {1 -> 2, 2 -> 4, 4 -> 1, 1 -> 3, 3 -> 4, 4 -> 5, 5 -> 3, 3 -> 2, 2 -> 4, 4 -> 1},
    {1 -> 2, 2 -> 4, 4 -> 1, 1 -> 3, 3 -> 2, 2 -> 4, 4 -> 5, 5 -> 3, 3 -> 4, 4 -> 1},
    {1 -> 2, 2 -> 4, 4 -> 1, 1 -> 3, 3 -> 4, 4 -> 5, 5 -> 3, 3 -> 2, 2 -> 4, 4 -> 1},
    {1 -> 2, 2 -> 4, 4 -> 1, 1 -> 3, 3 -> 2, 2 -> 4, 4 -> 5, 5 -> 3, 3 -> 4, 4 -> 1}}

Length[tours]
   16
```

The tour in the OP corresponds to the fifteenth entry:

```
Partition[Table[HighlightGraph[house, Take[tours[[15]], k]], {k, 8}], 4] // GraphicsGrid
```

[image: OP's path]

Comment: Neat! I spent a lot of time looking for the `FindPostmanTour` function and couldn't seem to in my naive documentation search. Great reply.

Comment: @user6014, thanks. Remembering the name of the problem surprisingly took more effort than coding it up. :D (Aside: please consider changing your username.)

Comment: Thank you ... this is very elegant. You show the possible solutions over 1->2->4->... . How do you find all solutions from all 5 starting points?

Comment: @mrz, you can rename the vertices so that `1` corresponds to your desired starting point. That, I'll leave for you as an exercise.

Comment: So it is wrong when I would define `edges = {1 -> 2, 1 -> 3, 1 -> 4, 2 -> 4, 2 -> 3, 2 -> 1, 3 -> 2, 
   3 -> 4, 3 -> 1, 3 -> 5, 4 -> 1, 4 -> 2, 4 -> 3, 4 -> 5, 5 -> 3, 
   5 -> 4};` and then use `FindPostmanTour`?

Comment: @mrz, `1 -> 4` means a directed path going from node `1` to node `4`, which seems to be the reverse of what's in your diagram.

Comment: @J.M. Beautiful.  But in version 8 the code does not run. Here's the correction. The line after house = ... should read Show[house], and as FindPostmanTour requires a graph object as the first parameter, the tours are calculated by FindPostmanTour[house,All].

Comment: @Dr. Hintze, unfortunately I did not have version 8 to check. The code as presented is working in 11, tho.

Comment: @J.M. No problem. Unfortunately this type of changes from version to version are not uncommon in Mathematica. But, again, very nice code the results of which I showed to my litle granddaughter who had the ambition of solving the puzzle by herself.

Comment: @J. M. see my update ...

Comment: @mrz, as I said, you can try relabeling the vertices so that `1` is some other vertex. Have you tried it already?

Comment: @J.M. I'm not sure anymore that this solution is correct. The first tour is {{1 -> 2, 2 -> 4, 4 -> 5, 5 -> 3, 3 -> 4, 4 -> 1, 1 -> 3, 3 -> 2, 2 -> 4, 4 -> 1},. It containes the edges 2->4 and 4->1 twice. Generally, we should have only 8 items in a tour, rather than 10.

Comment: @mrz IMHO the solution of J.M. is not correct as it draws some edges more than once. Please see my solution.

Comment: @Dr. Hintze, apparently so; let me think about it.

Comment: As [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_path),I think we should use `FindEulerianCycle` but not `FindPostmanTour`?

Comment: @yode, were you able to make `FindEulerianCycle[]` work in this case?

Comment: Yes,I can't.As the of the state of **You must not repeat a line.** Maybe this answer have some problem or maybe I miss something.I think this post want find a *eulerian path* from 1 to 2.I mean this is *half eulerian graph*

Comment: @J.M. To be honest, the valuations of the contributions to this problem look a bit strange to me. What do they measure?

Comment: @Dr.WolfgangHintze I have given a vote. :)

Comment: @J.M. I believe FindPostmanTour gives tours that traverse each edge _at least_ once. It seems to me the OP wants tours that traverse each edge _exactly_ once. Does it suffice to select from the tours you found those that have no duplicates?

Answer (score 7):

As [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_path),I think we want to find all of the *Eulerian path*.But *Mathematica* have no such function to do this directly.So I will delete the edge `1 <-> 2` first,then use `FindEulerianCycle` like follow:

- #### Make a intermediate graph without edge `1 <-> 2`:

  ```
  pts = {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}, {1/2, 1 + Sqrt[3]/2}};
  g = EdgeDelete[
  g1=Graph[{1 <-> 2, 2 <-> 3, 3 <-> 4, 1 <-> 3, 1 <-> 4, 2 <-> 4, 
  4 <-> 5, 3 <-> 5}, VertexCoordinates -> pts, 
  VertexLabels -> "Name"], 1 <-> 2]
  ```

[image]

- #### Find all of the *Eulerian path*:

  ```
  paths=Prepend[#, 1 <-> 2] & /@ FindEulerianCycle[g, All]
  ```

[image]

```
MapIndexed[
 Export[ToString@First[#2] <> ".gif", #, "DisplayDurations" -> 0.5] &,
  FoldList[HighlightGraph[#1, #2, GraphHighlightStyle -> "Thick"] &, 
    g1, #] & /@ paths]
```

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

**PS:** I found the vertex $3$,$4$,$1$ and $2$ is completely equivalent.I think this is a bug of `FindEulerianCycle` which cannot find another $18$ path at least.(I have reported it to W.R. as **CASE:3741151**.If I get any useful response,I will update it to here.)

Comment: (at) yode : I have solved the problem the other way round, i.e. adding a vertex and two edges. I have found no indications for a bug in FindEulerianCircles. See my full solution.

Comment: @Dr.WolfgangHintze Have you seen my PS in the end of post?

Comment: Sorry for responding so late. Did you check if there's an error in my solution stemming from your general observation of a bug?