# FindCurvePath for lines (rather than points)

Tags: computational-geometry, sorting

I have need of a function to find a good ordering for a series of lines, as [`FindCurvePath`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindCurvePath.html) does for points.

Sample data:

```
dat = {{{-2.83718,1.},{-2.83708,0.999885}},{{-2.837,0.999875},
{-2.83708,0.999885}},{{-2.83649,0.999763},{-2.83673,0.999716}},
{{-2.83673,0.999716},{-2.837,0.999875}},{{-2.83747,0.999718},{-2.83718,1.}},
{{-2.83699,0.999714},{-2.83697,0.999704}},{{-2.83696,0.999716},
{-2.8368,0.999686}},{{-2.83696,0.999716},{-2.83697,0.999704}},
{{-2.83678,0.999668},{-2.8368,0.999686}},{{-2.83702,0.999653},
{-2.83699,0.999714}},{{-2.83675,0.999644},{-2.83678,0.999668}},
{{-2.83647,0.999632},{-2.83649,0.999763}},{{-2.83647,0.999632},
{-2.8365,0.999633}},{{-2.8367,0.999603},{-2.83675,0.999644}},
{{-2.8365,0.999633},{-2.83654,0.999584}},{{-2.83666,0.99957},
{-2.8367,0.999603}},{{-2.83728,0.999697},{-2.83712,0.999592}},
{{-2.83664,0.999553},{-2.83666,0.99957}},{{-2.83654,0.999584},
{-2.83655,0.999551}},{{-2.83655,0.999551},{-2.83656,0.999549}},
{{-2.83712,0.999592},{-2.83702,0.999653}},{{-2.83656,0.999549},
{-2.83664,0.999553}}};
```

These lines form a single line:

```
ListLinePlot[dat, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

But they are out of order and their directions are mixed:

```
ListLinePlot[Join @@ dat, Frame -> True]
Graphics[Arrow @ dat, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

[image]

So I need not only to order the lines but to reverse some of them as well.

I also need to allow for gaps between lines.  End points will not always be as close as in this example.  A solution should work also on:

```
dat2 = dat ~Delete~ {{2}, {8}, {9}, {13}};

ListLinePlot[dat2, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

Additionally in practice my constituent lines are more than two points long but the end points should be sufficient for a solution.  However I either need ordering and direction data that I can apply to the full lines or an algorithm that works on compound lines, not just line segments.

---

## Benchmarking

With multiple methods posted it is time to being benchmarking.  The three methods are not entirely equivalent but I am making an effort to compare them as fairly as I can.

- Feyre's code does not return an explicit order but instead modified data
- my code is dependent on the specification of a suitable search radius
- Simon's `FindShortestTour` does not return an order starting with one of the ends
- I had to make a change and an addition to Simon's code to get consistent results
- I do not include application of the ordering produced by `segOrder1` and `segOrder2` in the benchmark but I found the overhead for that operation negligible

For random data I am using:

```
rdat[n_] := 
  RandomSample /@ Partition[RandomReal[1, {n, 2}], 2, 1] // RandomSample
```

The functions as I am benchmarking them:

```
segOrder1[segs_, rad_: 0.0001] := (
   Flatten[segs, 1]
     // Nearest[# -> Automatic, #, {2, rad}] &
     // Cases[{_, _}]
     // Join[#, Partition[Range[2 Length@segs], 2]] &
     // Graph
     // FindPath[#, ## & @@ GraphPeriphery[#]] &
     // First
  )

segOrder2[segs_] :=
  Module[{d = Flatten[segs, 1], dist},
    dist[a_?OddQ, b_] /; (b == a + 1) := 0;
    dist[a_, b_] := 1 + EuclideanDistance[d[[a]], d[[b]]];

    FindShortestTour[Range @ Length @ d, DistanceFunction -> dist][[2]]
      // If[#[[2]] === 2, Most, Rest][#] &
  ]

segReorder[dat_] :=
 Module[{newdat, z, k, temp, it},
  newdat = {dat[[1]]};
  z = 1; k = 1;
  While[k < Length@dat, 
   temp = Select[dat, FreeQ[Join[Reverse /@ newdat, newdat], #] &];
   it = Table[
     RegionDistance[Line@newdat[[k]], temp[[i, j]]], {i, Length[dat] - k}, {j, 2}];
   z = Position[it, Min@it][[1, 1]];
   If[it[[z, 1]] > it[[z, 2]], AppendTo[newdat, Reverse@temp[[z]]], 
    AppendTo[newdat, temp[[z]]]]; k++;];
  newdat
  ]
```

Confirmation that they are working on this data:

```
SeedRandom[1]
dat = rdat[20];
o1 = segOrder1[dat];
o2 = segOrder2[dat];
newdat = segReorder[dat];

Partition[Flatten[dat, 1][[#]], 2] & /@ {o1, o2};
Append[%, newdat];
Graphics[Arrow@#, ImageSize -> 200] & /@ % // Row
```

[image]

Benchmark Plot

```
Needs["GeneralUtilities`"]

BenchmarkPlot[{segOrder1, segOrder2, segReorder}, rdat, 5]
```

[image]

Comment: You can use a loop with minimizing `RegionDistance` but my attempts got rather messy. Easy if you know begin and end lines though.

Comment: @Feyre If you feel like posting something don't worry about it being messy.  I am curious to see multiple approaches.

Comment: Duplicate [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/118148/21532) maybe.

Comment: @yode That would appear to be a more advanced problem than mine.  I only need a single line start to finish, with no revisited points.  I find that problem very interesting as well however and you just got my vote on it.  I am sorry to see that there has not been more interest generally, but perhaps it was just posted at a poor time.

Comment: Related: [(111460)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/111460/121), [(118132)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/118132/121), and to a lesser degree [(102618)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/102618/121), [(222252)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/222252/121)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I think this question some time.I have to say it is very same to that.Hope help a little. :) And just a bit complaint here about that the vote indeed follow those high level user much too in SE.Such as [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/137786/21532) can get 16 votes,or such [wrong answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/128746/21532) collects 21 votes.Well,I have been confused it until now.But my good answer will often sink down.Perhaps the rich getting rich, the poor getting poor is a ture law in nature.Okay,I talk too much.The SE is a good site after all,

Comment: @Mr.Wizard and you also are my first responser here.I am very appreciate you and this site all the time. :)

Comment: @yode (1) yes, that question and its answer(s) will certainly be of help.  As I said I see it as a more advanced version of my question. (2) Surely there is some tendency for people to vote for posts by known personalities and I admit both that I am the recipient of this and that it's not fair.  Nevertheless I think this is a secondary factor to simple unpredictability of who sees what posts, and when.  I experience posts of mine going largely ignored, sometimes when I really tried to make them good, while other trivial answers get a bunch of votes. (continued)

Comment: Just to make a point if you think that all of my answers get lots of votes look at http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/121/mr-wizard?tab=answers&sort=votes&page=92 etc. and see otherwise.  Also remember that some of the most popular answers on this site are total nonsense (\*cough\* buttocks \*cough\*) so votes really aren't a terribly reliable measure of value.  In short my advice to you is don't be discouraged.  You really never know who is seeing and benefiting from your answers, or who will do so long in the future.  And *thank you* for letting me know that you appreciate me. :-)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Nonono,I'm not discourage at all.It a piddling thing. :) I just wanna share a "strange" phenomenon to you here:those high level user who don't care *rep* any more get vote more easier,as you know [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/31433/librarylink-what-can-we-do-with-minputstream-and-moutputstream#comment359372_31433),but one who care rep still difficultly to get it.I think this phenomenon also appear other place.Let it go.I will be hight level user in future,I hope.I can do more for this site,nice place that with a good tag system,better appearance than [wolfram

Comment: @Mr.Wizard than [wolfram community](http://community.wolfram.com/) and warm-heart user.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With the missing piece from [How do I "read out" the vertex names on this graph?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/136188/121) I can self-answer using [`Nearest`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Nearest.html) and [`Graph`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graph.html).  Please don't let this post discourage answering as I am eager to see other approaches.

Now as a function with at least a little reusability.  The second parameter is the search radius.

```
segOrder[segs_, rad_: 0.0001] := (
   Flatten[segs, 1]
     // Nearest[# -> Automatic, #, {2, rad}] &
     // Cases[{_, _}]
     // Join[#, Partition[Range[2 Length@segs], 2]] &
     // Graph
     // FindPath[#, ## & @@ GraphPeriphery[#]] &
     // First
  )

ListLinePlot[Part[Join @@ dat, segOrder[dat]], Frame -> True]
```

[image]

It works on the set with gaps given a sufficient radius:

```
ListLinePlot[Part[Join @@ dat2, segOrder[dat2, 0.0001]], Frame -> True]
```

[image]

#### Extension

Here is my application of this ordering to the sorting (and joining) of longer lines.

```
lineSort[lines_, r_: 0.0001] :=
  lines[[All, {1, -1}]] ~segOrder~ r ~Partition~ 2 //
    Cases[ {a_, b_} :> lines[[⌈a/2⌉, b - a ;; a - b ;; b - a]] ]
```

Now I can do things like this:

```
geo = Import["http://www.rr4w.com/kml/9.kml"];

Cases[geo, Line[x_] :> x, {-4}] // lineSort // Catenate;

Graphics[{
  Thickness[1/150], 
  Line[%, VertexColors -> Array[ColorData["Rainbow"], Length@%, {0, 1}]]
}]
```

[image]

Comment: How about a larger test set to enable benchmarking? I'm very interested to learn about the speed of different approaches (very relevant  for CNC path optimization...)

Comment: @YvesKlett Do you have a set to propose?  If uniformly distributed pseudorandom data useful?

Comment: ... will take a look if I find a wicked set tomorrow (sorry,  very busy at the office recently) . However, pseudorandom should work as well.

Comment: @YvesKlett A basic benchmark has been added to the Question.  I look forward to a real world set of a larger size than my original sample.

Answer (score 10):

Using `FindShortestTour` with a custom distance function:

```
d = Flatten[dat, 1];

dist[a_?OddQ, b_] /; (b == a + 1) := 0.0001 EuclideanDistance[d[[a]], d[[b]]]

dist[a_, b_] := EuclideanDistance[d[[a]], d[[b]]]

o = Most@FindShortestTour[Range[Length@d], DistanceFunction -> dist][[2]]
(* {1, 2, 4, 3, 8, 7, 6, 5, 24, 23, 25, 26, 29, 30, 37, 38, 39, \
40, 43, 44, 35, 36, 31, 32, 27, 28, 21, 22, 17, 18, 14, 13, 15, 16, \
12, 11, 20, 19, 42, 41, 34, 33, 9, 10} *)

Graphics[Arrow /@ Partition[d[[o]], 2]]
```

[image]

*Update*

A revised version which addresses Mr.Wizard's observations. Performance is still poor though.

```
segOrder2[segs_] :=
 Module[{d = Flatten[segs, 1], dist, o},
  dist[a_?OddQ, b_] /; (b == a + 1) := 0;
  dist[a_, b_] := 1 + EuclideanDistance[d[[a]], d[[b]]];
  o = FindShortestTour[Range[Length@d], DistanceFunction -> dist][[2]] // 
    If[#[[2]] === 2, Rest, Most][#] &;
  RotateLeft[o, 2 Ordering[dist @@@ Partition[o, 2], -1] - 1]]
```

Comment: Great!  I had a feeling there was a more direct approach but I could not see my way to it.  I knew I needed a way to "contract" the distance between points joined by existing lines but I struggled to do it.  Treating odd indices seems obvious now but it was not at the time, like so many great ideas.

Comment: I'm probably having another moment of obtuseness but why can one not use `dist[a_?OddQ, b_] /; (b == a + 1) := 0`?

Comment: There is one issue with this as written: the order always starts with {1} whereas in practice it should start with one of the ends, i.e. {9} or {33}.

Comment: To handle adjacent line segments that start and end on the same point I needed to add a constant to the distance, e.g. `dist[a_, b_] := 1 + EuclideanDistance[d[[a]], d[[b]]]`

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, you can use zero distance. An earlier attempt did not work with zero as it allowed lines to be traversed multiple times in both directions. I hadn't realised that my workaround was no longer necessary. The start point is a problem. `FindShortestTour` identifies a complete circuit so it could perhaps be post-processed to split at the largest gap.

Answer (score 9):

This approach generates the data into `newdat`.

```
newdat = {dat[[1]]};
z = 1; k = 1;
While[k < Length@dat, 
 temp = Select[dat, FreeQ[Join[Reverse /@ newdat, newdat], #] &];
 it = Table[
   RegionDistance[Line@newdat[[k]], temp[[i, j]]], {i, 
    Length[dat] - k}, {j, 2}];
 z = Position[it, Min@it][[1, 1]];
 If[it[[z, 1]] > it[[z, 2]], AppendTo[newdat, Reverse@temp[[z]]], 
  AppendTo[newdat, temp[[z]]]]; k++;]
```

And the results:

```
ListLinePlot[Join @@ newdat, Frame -> True]
Graphics[Arrow@newdat, Frame -> True]
```

[image]
[image]

For the reduced data one arrow stays reversed.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

For the sake of general,such as the line include not only $2$ points,the every line maybe is a mess order(include first one),I make some adjust like following.Maybe too long,but powerful.

#### If you have a gap data like `dat2`

We can convert it into non-gap data first by `ConnectComponentPoints`

```
ConnectComponentPoints[p_] := 
 Module[{f, var1, var2, nearePoint, graph}, f = Nearest /@ Most[p];
  var2 = Drop[p, #] & /@ Range[Length[p] - 1];
  var1 = MapThread[Catenate /@ # /@ #2 &, {f, var2}];
  nearePoint = 
   Catenate[
    Map[First[MinimalBy[#, EuclideanDistance @@ # &]] &, 
     Flatten[{var1, var2}, List /@ {2, 3, 4, 1, 5}], {2}]];
  graph = 
   CompleteGraph[Length[p], 
    EdgeWeight -> EuclideanDistance @@@ nearePoint];
  Join[p, 
   nearePoint[[EdgeIndex[graph, #] & /@ 
      EdgeList[FindSpanningTree[graph]]]]]]

ListLinePlot[ConnectComponentPoints[dat2]]
```

http://o8aucf9ny.bkt.clouddn.com/2017-02-18-20-30-50.png

#### If you have a non-gap data like `dat`:

```
ConnectLines[dat_] := 
 Module[{g = 
    SimpleGraph[RelationGraph[IntersectingQ, dat], 
     VertexLabels -> "Index"], path}, 
  path = FindShortestPath[g, Sequence @@ GraphPeriphery[g]];
  Append[First /@ #, #[[-1, -1]]] &[
   FoldPairList[(Transpose[
        DeleteDuplicates[
         SortBy[Tuples[{##}], N[EuclideanDistance @@ #] &], 
         ContainsAny]] // {Reverse[#], #2} & @@ # &) &, First[path], 
    Rest[path], Identity]]]

newdat = ConnectLines[dat];
ListLinePlot[Join @@ newdat, Frame -> True]
Graphics[Arrow@newdat, Frame -> True]
```

http://o8aucf9ny.bkt.clouddn.com/2017-02-18-20-28-53.png

Comment: It seems I do not have `RelationGraph` in *Mathematica* 10.1.  Based on the appearance of `IntersectingQ` I am guessing that this code does not handle the case with gaps, `dat2`, correct?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Yes,It cannot.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard But your this post is about no gap case or I misunderstand?

Comment: You mean my self-answer?  It does work on the case with gaps as I showed.  As noted in the question *I also need to allow for gaps between lines. End points will not always be as close as in this example.*  Nevertheless I will vote for your answer for showing me `RelationGraph`.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard In your gap case,do you wanna leave the maximal gap as your self-answer or whatever it is?

Comment: Yes, the idea is to complete a single continuous line but there is no expectation that it forms a closed circuit.  However I welcome a *fast* solution that does either, i.e. beats the performance of Simon Woods's answer in either form.