# Get all pairs of same consecutive characters from string?

Tags: string-manipulation

Consider a string like:

```
str = "AabHHioPjggtYuggbwq";
```

I would like to have a function `getpairs[x_String]` that would extract for me:

```
getpairs[str]
```

> `{"Aa","HH","gg","gg"}`

Any suggestions how to do this?

Comment: Could your input contain something like `aaa`? If so do you expect one or two `aa` in the result? (Or alternatively, if there's `aAa`, do you want both `aA` and `Aa`?)

Comment: Good point! I did not think about 3 letters yet. I guess if 3 appear, I would like to take them out separately. So, extract all occurrences of repeated letters (two or more). In your example: `...,"aaa",...,"aAa",...,`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
str = "AabHHioPjggtYuggbwq";
StringCases[str, x_ ~~ x_, IgnoreCase -> True]
```

> `{"Aa", "HH", "gg", "gg"}`

Or in the generalized version of the question:

```
str = "AaAbHHhhhioPjggtYuggGgGbwq";
StringCases[str, x_ ~~ (x_) .., IgnoreCase -> True]
```

> `{"AaA", "HHhhh", "gg", "ggGgG"}`

Comment: After the OP's clarification in a comment on the question, I think this should be `x_ ~~ x_ ..`.

Comment: Funny. :)This deserve 10 vote(include my one.)?

Comment: the generalized case needs parenthesis: `x_ ~~ (x_) ..`

Comment: I'd generalize by allowing overlaps, at least that's how the question reads to me

Comment: @LLlAMnYP No, OP clarified how he wants to handle more than two of the same character in a row, in his comment. That's what the generalized version is for.

Comment: @C.E. a re-read shows that you're right

Comment: @george2079 Not really, the space is sufficient. However, for some reason when copying the string without parenthesis into Mathematica, it just removes the space (if you reinserted manually it works). The worst part about that is that this short snippet doesn't survive a roundtrip transform out of and back into Mathematica. Maybe this should be reported as a bug...

Comment: @MartinEnder right you are. It is odd the space seems to be required to avoid ambiguity with a single dot `x_.` default pattern, but there should be no issue since that is (apparently) not valid in a string expression anyway.

Answer (score 5):

```
getpairs[str_String] := StringJoin @@@ Select[
   Partition[Characters[str], 2, 1],
   SameQ @@ ToUpperCase[#] &]

str = "AabHHioPjggtYuggbwq";

getpairs[str]

(*  {"Aa", "HH", "gg", "gg"}  *)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't generalise easily to the OP's comment on the question in the case of more than 2 consecutive occurrences of a letter.

Comment: @MartinEnder Well, we can't be expected to be prescient...

Comment: @C.E. No, but I think it's a good idea to think about edge cases the OP might be overlooking (or neglected to mention) and ask for clarification before answering.

Comment: @MartinEnder The title mentions "pairs", the name of the function in the question is "getpairs". So you would have us ask, "do you mean pairs?" I don't buy it. It's better to post the answer and wait for a reaction from OP, who may choose to request improvements if he wants. Needless to say, one should not post an answer if one does not understand the question. But both Bob and I got it right, as evidenced by the fact that my answer was accepted without the general case.

Comment: @C.E. Yes, the question says "pairs". Nevertheless, it was completely unclear what *should* happen to the input `"aAa"` (or whether the OP assumes that this case will never appear in the input).

Comment: @MartinEnder There is a representative string in the question and there were no such cases in that representative string... "How do you know that it is representative?" That is the point of MWEs.

Answer (score 5):

I will give a `RegularExpression` version here.

```
str = "AabHHioPjggtYuggbwq";
StringCases[str, RegularExpression["(?i)(\\w)\\1"]]
```

> {"Aa", "HH", "gg", "gg"}

---

Per [this comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/137780/get-all-pairs-of-same-consecutive-characters-from-string/137786#comment371963_137780),that the string contain 3 or more letter case

```
str = "aAabHhHioPjggtYuggbwwq";
StringCases[str, RegularExpression["(?i)(\\w)\\1+"]]
```

> {"aAa", "HhH", "gg", "gg", "ww"}

Comment: You can use `\\1+` instead of `\\1*\\1` (and it would be marginally more efficient to switch that around to `\\1\\1*` if you kept it). Also note that `\\w` matches more than just letters (but not all characters either).

Comment: @MartinEnder Wow,thanks for your advice.