# How to sort lines into continous paths efficiently

Tags: performance-tuning, sorting

As part of my work I get a bunch of lines from my co-worker. (Background: I do electromagnetic designs, my co-worker does the mechanical design). These lines are in random order, but I need them in continous paths, with all line segments running in the same direction.

I've created a small example, real work consists of several thousand lines.

Create some test data:

```
(* create some test data *)
spiral1 = N@Table[{p Cos[p], p Sin[p]}, {p, Pi, 4 Pi, Pi/16}];
spiral2 = 
  N@Table[{p Cos[p + Pi], p Sin[p + Pi]}, {p, Pi, 5 Pi, Pi/16}];
lines = Join[Partition[spiral1, 2, 1], Partition[spiral2, 2, 1]];
(* scramble *)
randomLines = 
  MapAt[Reverse, RandomSample@lines, 
   List /@ RandomChoice[Range[Length[lines]], 
     Floor[Length[lines]/2]]];
```

And see what we've got:

```
Graphics[Table[{Hue[i/Length[randomLines]], 
   Arrow@randomLines[[i]]}, {i, Length[randomLines]}] ]
```

[image: Random lines as input]

These lines are now sorted (code below):

```
sorted = mySort[randomLines];
```

The random lines were sorted into seperate paths with a continous direction of the lines. (The total direction of each path is still random, but that's OK for me).

Looks as expected:

```
Graphics[Table[{PointSize[0.05], Hue[i/Length[sorted]], 
   Point[sorted[[i, 1, 1]]], Arrow@sorted[[i]], GrayLevel[0], 
   Text[i, sorted[[i, 1, 1]], {0, 0}]}, {i, Length[sorted]}] ]
```

[image: Sorted lines]

My question now is, how can I make my prodedural code more Mathematica-like? And hopefully more efficient? For real work, my code is too slow.

**Code:**

```
mySort[in : {{{_?NumberQ ..}, {_?NumberQ ..}} ..}] := Module[
  {sorted, pool, this, found,
   tol = 10.0*^-9},
  
  (* start *)
  sorted = {{First[in]}};
  pool = Rest[in];
  
  While[Length[pool] > 0,
   
   found = False;
   (* use the last of all sorted paths that were found so far,
      the other paths are already complete *)
   
   For[i = 1, i <= Length[pool] && Not[found], i++,
    this = pool[[i]];
    (* check if this fits onto the sorted line path *)
    found = Which[
      (* this fits on end *)
      Norm[sorted[[-1, -1, -1]] - this[[1]]] < tol,
        sorted[[-1]] = Append[sorted[[-1]], this];
        True,
      (* reversed this fits on end *)
      Norm[sorted[[-1, -1, -1]] - this[[-1]]] < tol,
        sorted[[-1]] = Append[sorted[[-1]], Reverse@this];
        True,
      (* this fits on beginning *)
      Norm[sorted[[-1, 1, 1]] - this[[-1]]] < tol,
        sorted[[-1]] = Prepend[sorted[[-1]], this];
        True,
      (* reversed this fits on beginning *)
      Norm[sorted[[-1, 1, 1]] - this[[1]]] < tol,
        sorted[[-1]] = Prepend[sorted[[-1]], Reverse@this];
        True,
      (* nothing found *)
      True,
        False
      ](* end of which *);
    ](* end of for *);
   
   (* remove from unsorted list *)
   pool = DeleteCases[pool, this];
   
   If[Not[found],
    (* need to start a new path *)
    sorted = Append[sorted, {this}];
    ];
   ](* end of while *);
  
  (* return result *)
  sorted
  ]
```

**Edit:**

Real world data:

```
randomLines = {{{-0.1732811503690476`, 
     0.3235849266204875`}, {-0.17359189280402723`, 
     0.3225643511484479`}}, {{-0.003790604496207962`, 
     0.330308955004866`}, {-0.004423377968477279`, 
     0.331138019882757`}}, {{-0.1609083437046747`, 
     0.32692061568805486`}, {-0.16038815001632004`, 
     0.3272754550920334`}}, {{-0.15872690806364326`, 
     0.3281712493076333`}, {-0.1592959532338122`, 
     0.3279016198019645`}}, {{-0.0274412108919291`, 
     0.29769071153521204`}, {-0.02718659256118707`, 
     0.29769509804809235`}}, {{-0.005814165101646035`, 
     0.33269164676889584`}, {-0.0050985101499539795`, 
     0.3319329710614432`}}, {{-0.13803406459546397`, 
     0.3404086542534827`}, {-0.145936615236459`, 
     0.339332441377564`}}, {{-0.022642808371541714`, 
     0.32717602179538546`}, {-0.022729514890690448`, 
     0.32742192097588857`}}, {{-0.16278418842931225`, 
     0.3252461150235488`}, {-0.16319556509908598`, 
     0.3247693743061922`}}, {{-0.17411145452597812`, 
     0.31410618140280167`}, {-0.17392795919535808`, 
     0.3130552462865045`}}, {{-0.132713447337878`, 
     0.30208331443021597`}, {-0.100026515355456`, 
     0.299751289764415`}}, {{-0.16899889159931059`, 
     0.33089743916120096`}, {-0.16826085579381164`, 
     0.33166778863048574`}}, {{-0.1643853934095711`, 
     0.3111863043989262`}, {-0.16406316733242707`, 
     0.31064530270648133`}}, {{-0.0006761538014226468`, 
     0.32374979504491025`}, {-0.0009712334861680851`, 
     0.32475013439663575`}}, {{-0.025224324645915733`, 
     0.2981887157630561`}, {-0.02499793734353272`, 
     0.29830532847747804`}}, {{-0.002163040134773521`, 
     0.32764005039517213`}, {-0.002658896809373818`, 
     0.3285575889487024`}}, {{-0.02242717528344411`, 
     0.3261574150385962`}, {-0.022461075109788706`, 
     0.3264159401422299`}}, {{-0.1635815832005517`, 
     0.32427187807368313`}, {-0.16394119730653092`, 
     0.3237549736620164`}}, {{-0.1633365381686077`, 
     0.30961720440672075`}, {-0.16371323301748703`, 
     0.3101217967836426`}}, {{-0.023674627537488186`, 
     0.3289717309615873`}, {-0.0238535412754112`, 
     0.32916139988845045`}}, {{-0.1654951793842912`, 
     0.3203275606355335`}, {-0.16564700675086885`, 
     0.31971644613989636`}}, {{-0.155936889548458`, 
     0.305189994603436`}, {-0.151503418460591`, 
     0.304406838304457`}}, {{-0.0727958373952835`, 
     0.26461098116609705`}, {-0.0428039479687876`, 
     0.263913436451513`}}, {{-0.022458263874178742`, 
     0.3019294608469123`}, {-0.022503423487267513`, 
     0.30167884092513675`}}, {{-0.026932527807086413`, 
     0.2977124426890192`}, {-0.02667967567091477`, 
     0.2977427004661773`}}, {{-0.09969648248885901`, 
     0.34301571998361696`}, {-0.11556475510930601`, 
     0.342302617147025`}}, {{-0.024358427676212165`, 
     0.2987220611582121`}, {-0.02456442659753365`, 
     0.2985723474973141`}}, {{-0.16748374342973676`, 
     0.33239870006741085`}, {-0.16826085579381164`, 
     0.33166778863048574`}}, {{-0.00010870113377766444`, 
     0.32067570736947887`}, {-0.0002443004391560457`, 
     0.3217098077840136`}}, {{-0.16493948767647237`, 
     0.3343355772937574`}, {-0.16402808627327933`, 
     0.3348900884634228`}}, {{-0.15844348057804805`, 
     0.29713091408852776`}, {-0.15947637636786122`, 
     0.29739786247756983`}}, {{-0.152964624886857`, 
     0.29613490529095693`}, {-0.143169407399232`, 
     0.29466514291458284`}}, {{-0.16517748475198532`, 
     0.31289941951686434`}, {-0.16494330760031867`, 
     0.31231489104223104`}}, {{-0.16371323301748703`, 
     0.3101217967836426`}, {-0.16406316733242707`, 
     0.31064530270648133`}}, {{-0.023305316984615142`, 
     0.29982112172172065`}, {-0.02345672343999681`, 
     0.29961636376433226`}}, {{-0.0009712334861680851`, 
     0.32475013439663575`}, {-0.0013180595627630184`, 
     0.32573373111864834`}}, {{-0.16590929240988667`, 
     0.3178473879987169`}, {-0.16593153282153464`, 
     0.3172180885150769`}}, {{-0.026848640006224257`, 
     0.33060633189857275`}, {-0.026590329679737904`, 
     0.3305708325652618`}}, {{-0.026334221152176908`, 
     0.3305219158038651`}, {-0.026081010879205578`, 
     0.33045971463750307`}}, {{-0.17034984968281547`, 
     0.3292468724279576`}, {-0.1696958520728942`, 
     0.3300897379458447`}}, {{-0.0002443004391560457`, 
     0.3217098077840136`}, {-0.00043362294146330525`, 
     0.3227354333633945`}}, {{-0.17171167689644382`, 
     0.3070770988467576`}, {-0.17116575668310063`, 
     0.30616052573145847`}}, {{-0.027441210891929108`, 
     0.29769071153521137`}, {-0.02809403765865751`, 
     0.29769725829732896`}}, {{-0.147200993609053`, 
     0.330628833209078`}, {-0.15633408725220094`, 
     0.3289440070126807`}}, {{-0.14462682853728007`, 
     0.3310351852767413`}, {-0.13707737058449998`, 
     0.33206331204543804`}}, {{-0.15949588000939435`, 
     0.30641294482771697`}, {-0.15893195007983538`, 
     0.30613277432504504`}}, {{-0.02710844968845011`, 
     0.33062831726772385`}, {-0.026848640006224257`, 
     0.33060633189857275`}}, {{-0.16666965910887294`, 
     0.3330881939930908`}, {-0.16748374342973676`, 
     0.33239870006741085`}}, {{-0.02545635562717863`, 
     0.29808378073754377`}, {-0.025224324645915733`, 
     0.2981887157630561`}}, {{-0.024882153503301283`, 
     0.3299565988498384`}, {-0.02511076646419278`, 
     0.3300819804336035`}}, {{-0.16696481100080182`, 
     0.3013644638663228`}, {-0.16776592565280904`, 
     0.30206898531338117`}}, {{-0.1692528790331332`, 
     0.3035981772336514`}, {-0.16993469074439835`, 
     0.30441870629797974`}}, {{-0.128043266825506`, 
     0.341430487537209`}, {-0.12177581745677402`, 
     0.341920407137907`}}, {{-0.01472404351682356`, 
     0.33788490576510627`}, {-0.015736884608708875`, 
     0.3381337104305543`}}, {{-0.026334221152176908`, 
     0.3305219158038651`}, {-0.026590329679737904`, 
     0.3305708325652618`}}, {{-0.16013211147715362`, 
     0.3366134464966566`}, {-0.1611384428627671`, 
     0.33625928227294805`}}, {{-0.1630890716399921`, 
     0.33539643486016946`}, {-0.16212498684755708`, 
     0.335853245179691`}}, {{-0.023347651124051683`, 
     0.32856572694744296`}, {-0.02350584449211901`, 
     0.3287729931669158`}}, {{-0.02291625928387132`, 
     0.3004778353939403`}, {-0.022809415381982865`, 
     0.30070899360053127`}}, {{-0.17424002851016965`, 
     0.3151652394208606`}, {-0.17411145452597812`, 
     0.31410618140280167`}}, {{-0.015736884608708875`, 
     0.3381337104305543`}, {-0.01676131871895284`, 
     0.3383293774761414`}}, {{-0.16899889159931059`, 
     0.33089743916120096`}, {-0.1696958520728942`, 
     0.3300897379458447`}}, {{-0.1738491209870721`, 
     0.3215289918789799`}, {-0.17405213828418334`, 
     0.3204816528068072`}}, {{-0.16494330760031867`, 
     0.31231489104223104`}, {-0.16467903858544197`, 
     0.31174333670203586`}}, {{-0.16569354052258883`, 
     0.3147148694731183`}, {-0.1655531098533738`, 
     0.31410103586116495`}}, {{-0.16509726199592512`, 
     0.32152198007933014`}, {-0.16485224962736336`, 
     0.3221020502606631`}}, {{-0.1624723720816022`, 
     0.2985153330191076`}, {-0.16149355361319787`, 
     0.2980910105462918`}}, {{-0.16612812978222688`, 
     0.3007025728681141`}, {-0.1652581479252421`, 
     0.30008510487417167`}}, {{-0.01676131871895284`, 
     0.3383293774761414`}, {-0.017794560024898265`, 
     0.3384713748093851`}}, {{-0.02316453209371017`, 
     0.30003332292421014`}, {-0.02303473396180133`, 
     0.30025241692412363`}}, {{-0.0050985101499539795`, 
     0.3319329710614432`}, {-0.004423377968477279`, 
     0.331138019882757`}}, {{-0.022940760033693074`, 
     0.32789850079501953`}, {-0.022828922220079186`, 
     0.3276629658063637`}}, {{-0.0783810716952149`, 
     0.298695519500128`}, {-0.0639031537148027`, 
     0.298252896713245`}}, {{-0.02718659256118707`, 
     0.29769509804809235`}, {-0.026932527807086413`, 
     0.2977124426890192`}}, {{-0.17171167689644382`, 
     0.3070770988467576`}, {-0.17220917492167956`, 
     0.3080208312611169`}}, {{-0.17095911325079685`, 
     0.3283711252842246`}, {-0.17034984968281547`, 
     0.3292468724279576`}}, {{-0.16485224962736336`, 
     0.3221020502606631`}, {-0.16457739200185012`, 
     0.3226685886633482`}}, {{-0.017794560024898265`, 
     0.3384713748093851`}, {-0.018833798753801673`, 
     0.3385593162859895`}}, {{-0.17057289276109477`, 
     0.30527359420929356`}, {-0.16993469074439835`, 
     0.30441870629797974`}}, {{-0.0961177437851361`, 
     0.291104503068724`}, {-0.0818949634250089`, 
     0.290426822082235`}}, {{-0.0957179577176685`, 
     0.299494984050185`}, {-0.0814951773575412`, 
     0.29881730306369597`}}, {{-0.16593153282153464`, 
     0.3172180885150769`}, {-0.16592100502526022`, 
     0.31658848416191104`}}, {{-0.02303473396180133`, 
     0.30025241692412363`}, {-0.02291625928387132`, 
     0.3004778353939403`}}, {{-0.16576683647257845`, 
     0.3190982606387603`}, {-0.16585434402254567`, 
     0.318474678322848`}}, {{-0.115187648877698`, 
     0.333911086244378`}, {-0.099319376257251`, 
     0.334624189080969`}}, {{-0.02250840573536552`, 
     0.3266723465370751`}, {-0.022461075109788706`, 
     0.3264159401422299`}}, {{-0.09711594348365293`, 
     0.3430650032516095`}, {-0.09969648248885887`, 
     0.34301571998361635`}}, {{-0.024660387516507672`, 
     0.3298194701710857`}, {-0.024446071569157422`, 
     0.32967096730193374`}}, {{-0.15947637636786122`, 
     0.29739786247756983`}, {-0.16049398602111695`, 
     0.2977181837984753`}}, {{-0.022729514890690448`, 
     0.32742192097588857`}, {-0.022828922220079186`, 
     0.3276629658063637`}}, {{-0.16319556509908598`, 
     0.3247693743061922`}, {-0.1635815832005517`, 
     0.32427187807368313`}}, {{-0.17095911325079685`, 
     0.3283711252842246`}, {-0.1715219927487946`, 
     0.32746486824245347`}}, {{-0.17424002851016965`, 
     0.3151652394208606`}, {-0.1743133329395534`, 
     0.3162295521642113`}}, {{-0.17420039487710307`, 
     0.3194251703707574`}, {-0.17429348925235025`, 
     0.31836240577202296`}}, {{-0.1565539214362742`, 
     0.3053156294928492`}, {-0.1571635818780663`, 
     0.3054731941517472`}}, {{-0.16612812978222688`, 
     0.3007025728681141`}, {-0.16696481100080182`, 
     0.3013644638663228`}}, {{-0.16467903858544197`, 
     0.31174333670203586`}, {-0.1643853934095711`, 
     0.3111863043989262`}}, {{-0.13480393096839502`, 
     0.34077895057190805`}, {-0.12804326682550607`, 
     0.34143048753720934`}}, {{-0.164273433498032`, 
     0.3232200609690685`}, {-0.16457739200185012`, 
     0.3226685886633482`}}, {{-0.022809415381982865`, 
     0.30070899360053127`}, {-0.022714479408088534`, 
     0.30094529192195113`}}, {{-0.16057623728510573`, 
     0.30705932259071705`}, {-0.16004447098197933`, 
     0.30672207331365464`}}, {{-0.09717236780491953`, 
     0.33466519275993967`}, {-0.09931937625725092`, 
     0.3346241890809694`}}, {{-0.0223999999999996`, 
     0.325636824663719`}, {-0.0223999999999996`, 
     0.302690541698566`}}, {{-0.00992861401320636`, 
     0.33587244261444776`}, {-0.009041550066031922`, 
     0.335323927899437`}}, {{-0.15949588000939435`, 
     0.30641294482771697`}, {-0.16004447098197933`, 
     0.30672207331365464`}}, {{-0.16590929240988667`, 
     0.3178473879987169`}, {-0.16585434402254567`, 
     0.318474678322848`}}, {{-0.006568396687868179`, 
     0.3334119838797717`}, {-0.007359153868518696`, 
     0.334092023525829`}}, {{-0.00002719377097363207`, 
     0.3196359442287738`}, {-0.00010870113377766444`, 
     0.32067570736947887`}}, {{-0.02583138743504106`, 
     0.3303843982146031`}, {-0.026081010879205578`, 
     0.33045971463750307`}}, {{3.5213168757718605`*^-16, 
     0.30059334586997`}, {3.73217884139672`*^-16, 
     0.31859334586997`}}, {{-0.133311219642531`, 
     0.293704611173041`}, {-0.100624287660109`, 
     0.29137258650724`}}, {{-0.023789803523763194`, 
     0.2992312814592999`}, {-0.02397061314593002`, 
     0.2990519560110863`}}, {{-0.09571795771766846`, 
     0.29949498405018493`}, {-0.10002651535545698`, 
     0.299751289764415`}}, {{-0.1633365381686077`, 
     0.30961720440672075`}, {-0.16293410296342192`, 
     0.30913289212972694`}}, {{-0.0238535412754112`, 
     0.32916139988845045`}, {-0.024042099171966737`, 
     0.3293414841661694`}}, {{-0.02583138743504106`, 
     0.3303843982146031`}, {-0.02558602963996038`, 
     0.33029617134892064`}}, {{-0.02558602963996038`, 
     0.33029617134892064`}, {-0.025345604714332153`, 
     0.33019527396257353`}}, {{-0.0449731659616852`, 
     0.29789667279542403`}, {-0.0280940376586573`, 
     0.29769725829732896`}}, {{-0.1725026316455957`, 
     0.32557071786870867`}, {-0.17203696376766003`, 
     0.32653055565838185`}}, {{-0.17405213828418334`, 
     0.3204816528068072`}, {-0.17420039487710307`, 
     0.3194251703707574`}}, {{-0.17305364983193894`, 
     0.3099794839639255`}, {-0.17265690341795825`, 
     0.3089891671267368`}}, {{-0.15872690806364326`, 
     0.3281712493076333`}, {-0.1581446064921331`, 
     0.3284109102260923`}}, {{-0.16564700675086885`, 
     0.31971644613989636`}, {-0.16576683647257845`, 
     0.3190982606387603`}}, {{-0.024777780966299914`, 
     0.29843331638866044`}, {-0.02456442659753365`, 
     0.2985723474973141`}}, {{-0.16852930413265976`, 
     0.3028142292006602`}, {-0.16776592565280904`, 
     0.30206898531338117`}}, {{-0.09453629942331661`, 
     0.342981057317432`}, {-0.0188337987538017`, 
     0.338559316285989`}}, {{-0.02618022798853192`, 
     0.29784160818282895`}, {-0.025934928004331545`, 
     0.2979100015567508`}}, {{-0.02416031856136073`, 
     0.2988820690157`}, {-0.024358427676212165`, 
     0.2987220611582121`}}, {{-0.02397061314593002`, 
     0.2990519560110863`}, {-0.02416031856136073`, 
     0.2988820690157`}}, {{-0.1592959532338122`, 
     0.3279016198019645`}, {-0.15985020089541102`, 
     0.3276027519287627`}}, {{-0.143169407399232`, 
     0.29466514291458284`}, {-0.133311219642531`, 
     0.293704611173041`}}, {{-0.16580184752261332`, 
     0.31533517751737167`}, {-0.16569354052258883`, 
     0.3147148694731183`}}, {{-0.006568396687868179`, 
     0.3334119838797717`}, {-0.005814165101646035`, 
     0.33269164676889584`}}, {{-0.02499793734353272`, 
     0.29830532847747804`}, {-0.024777780966299914`, 
     0.29843331638866044`}}, {{-0.16342779055730133`, 
     0.29899000205256`}, {-0.16435722154391225`, 
     0.2995137321320412`}}, {{-0.023200477620708284`, 
     0.32835049593817933`}, {-0.023347651124051683`, 
     0.32856572694744296`}}, {{-0.023064724202343147`, 
     0.3281278854334021`}, {-0.023200477620708284`, 
     0.32835049593817933`}}, {{-0.16057623728510573`, 
     0.30705932259071705`}, {-0.16108973877142355`, 
     0.30742377930909276`}}, {{-0.024660387516507672`, 
     0.3298194701710857`}, {-0.024882153503301283`, 
     0.3299565988498384`}}, {{-0.012744118559842758`, 
     0.3372307326107764`}, {-0.011782418857329856`, 
     0.3368271430653881`}}, {{-0.0017156888803179662`, 
     0.326697910440549`}, {-0.002163040134773521`, 
     0.32764005039517213`}}, {{-0.0223999999999996`, 
     0.325636824663719`}, {-0.022406798442743105`, 
     0.32589747425341997`}}, {{-0.16538093583401997`, 
     0.31349533908630195`}, {-0.16517748475198532`, 
     0.31289941951686434`}}, {{-0.16342779055730133`, 
     0.29899000205256`}, {-0.1624723720816022`, 
     0.2985153330191076`}}, {{-0.159108718071151`, 
     0.3369147786913791`}, {-0.15807103423313`, 
     0.33716246277915196`}}, {{-0.02545635562717863`, 
     0.29808378073754377`}, {-0.025693428401407696`, 
     0.2979907956012883`}}, {{-0.16234856729533484`, 
     0.3257008091005413`}, {-0.16278418842931225`, 
     0.3252461150235488`}}, {{-0.003790604496207962`, 
     0.330308955004866`}, {-0.0032019104828343607`, 
     0.32944803096781144`}}, {{-0.0017156888803179662`, 
     0.326697910440549`}, {-0.0013180595627630184`, 
     0.32573373111864834`}}, {{-0.09611774378513621`, 
     0.291104503068723`}, {-0.10062428766010907`, 
     0.2913725865072393`}}, {{-0.1733983396816671`, 
     0.310989099763386`}, {-0.17369003946652273`, 
     0.3120152802497241`}}, {{-0.17265690341795825`, 
     0.3089891671267368`}, {-0.17220917492167956`, 
     0.3080208312611169`}}, {{-0.1655531098533738`, 
     0.31410103586116495`}, {-0.16538093583401997`, 
     0.31349533908630195`}}, {{-0.1609083437046747`, 
     0.32692061568805486`}, {-0.16140937315446863`, 
     0.32653919470481063`}}, {{-0.16250701729045952`, 
     0.30867017158342486`}, {-0.16293410296342192`, 
     0.30913289212972694`}}, {{-0.1569465738102524`, 
     0.3287978129901419`}, {-0.156334087252201`, 
     0.32894400701268106`}}, {{-0.02361835871310968`, 
     0.2994195801920229`}, {-0.02345672343999681`, 
     0.29961636376433226`}}, {{-0.1725026316455957`, 
     0.32557071786870867`}, {-0.17291773524522516`, 
     0.3245879543383512`}}, {{-0.1611384428627671`, 
     0.33625928227294805`}, {-0.16212498684755708`, 
     0.335853245179691`}}, {{-0.16049398602111695`, 
     0.2977181837984753`}, {-0.16149355361319787`, 
     0.2980910105462918`}}, {{-0.022503423487267513`, 
     0.30167884092513675`}, {-0.022561284768092122`, 
     0.3014308453444776`}}, {{-0.011782418857329856`, 
     0.3368271430653881`}, {-0.010843065856772359`, 
     0.336373968949508`}}, {{-0.007359153868518696`, 
     0.334092023525829`}, {-0.008184286276630927`, 
     0.334729916422829`}}, {{-0.17291773524522516`, 
     0.3245879543383512`}, {-0.1732811503690476`, 
     0.3235849266204875`}}, {{-0.17369003946652273`, 
     0.3120152802497241`}, {-0.17392795919535808`, 
     0.3130552462865045`}}, {{-0.17116575668310063`, 
     0.30616052573145847`}, {-0.17057289276109477`, 
     0.30527359420929356`}}, {{-0.08149517735754128`, 
     0.298817303063696`}, {-0.07838107169521498`, 
     0.2986955195001285`}}, {{-0.151503418460592`, 
     0.304406838304457`}, {-0.14213853479564478`, 
     0.30300164707850935`}}, {{-0.16402808627327933`, 
     0.3348900884634228`}, {-0.1630890716399921`, 
     0.33539643486016946`}}, {{-0.013725549740165472`, 
     0.33758364007350633`}, {-0.012744118559842758`, 
     0.3372307326107764`}}, {{-0.022458263874178742`, 
     0.3019294608469123`}, {-0.022425923072385`, 
     0.3021820550043753`}}, {{-0.14851078030823212`, 
     0.33892608930990176`}, {-0.15807103423313001`, 
     0.337162462779152`}}, {{-0.17433116928861334`, 
     0.31729623722536016`}, {-0.1743133329395534`, 
     0.3162295521642113`}}, {{-0.0950261039467197`, 
     0.334595349742704`}, {-0.09717236780491953`, 
     0.33466519275993967`}}, {{-0.1715219927487946`, 
     0.32746486824245347`}, {-0.17203696376766003`, 
     0.32653055565838185`}}, {{-0.024042099171966737`, 
     0.3293414841661694`}, {-0.024239788467129365`, 
     0.3295114940776837`}}, {{-0.115187648877698`, 
     0.333911086244378`}, {-0.12112119567347102`, 
     0.3335459537037523`}}, {{-0.02263169762510149`, 
     0.3011861174028509`}, {-0.022714479408088534`, 
     0.30094529192195113`}}, {{-0.12738864504220201`, 
     0.333056034103054`}, {-0.13384723695743`, 
     0.33243360836386193`}}, {{-0.026428692048441692`, 
     0.2977857928912122`}, {-0.02618022798853192`, 
     0.29784160818282895`}}, {{-0.1569465738102524`, 
     0.3287978129901419`}, {-0.15755062552794172`, 
     0.3286199534995984`}}, {{-0.16531176555681543`, 
     0.32092994908488376`}, {-0.16509726199592512`, 
     0.32152198007933014`}}, {{-0.159108718071151`, 
     0.3369147786913791`}, {-0.16013211147715362`, 
     0.3366134464966566`}}, {{-0.023789803523763194`, 
     0.2992312814592999`}, {-0.02361835871310968`, 
     0.2994195801920229`}}, {{-0.02316453209371017`, 
     0.30003332292421014`}, {-0.023305316984615142`, 
     0.29982112172172065`}}, {{-0.16234856729533484`, 
     0.3257008091005413`}, {-0.1618898814609297`, 
     0.32613222511940926`}}, {{-0.022406798442743105`, 
     0.32589747425341997`}, {-0.02242717528344411`, 
     0.3261574150385962`}}, {{-0.02667967567091477`, 
     0.2977427004661773`}, {-0.026428692048441692`, 
     0.2977857928912122`}}, {{-0.16140937315446863`, 
     0.32653919470481063`}, {-0.1618898814609297`, 
     0.32613222511940926`}}, {{-0.1692528790331332`, 
     0.3035981772336514`}, {-0.16852930413265976`, 
     0.3028142292006602`}}, {{-0.02263169762510149`, 
     0.3011861174028509`}, {-0.022561284768092122`, 
     0.3014308453444776`}}, {{-0.12177581745677403`, 
     0.341920407137907`}, {-0.115564755109306`, 
     0.3423026171470251`}}, {{-0.16531176555681543`, 
     0.32092994908488376`}, {-0.1654951793842912`, 
     0.3203275606355335`}}, {{-0.008184286276630927`, 
     0.334729916422829`}, {-0.009041550066031922`, 
     0.335323927899437`}}, {{-0.13480393096839502`, 
     0.34077895057190805`}, {-0.138034064595464`, 
     0.340408654253483`}}, {{-0.02350584449211901`, 
     0.3287729931669158`}, {-0.023674627537488186`, 
     0.3289717309615873`}}, {{-0.013725549740165472`, 
     0.33758364007350633`}, {-0.01472404351682356`, 
     0.33788490576510627`}}, {{-0.0639031537148028`, 
     0.29825289671324495`}, {-0.061660627893130995`, 
     0.29819810751174`}}, {{-0.04497316596168523`, 
     0.29789667279542326`}, {-0.046157143827387906`, 
     0.297914496015335`}}, {{-0.022406484973584426`, 
     0.3024359681709503`}, {-0.022399999999999913`, 
     0.302690541698566`}}, {{-0.158354208447265`, 
     0.30588232057279774`}, {-0.15776421977096358`, 
     0.30566226185823286`}}, {{-0.13384723695743`, 
     0.332433608363862`}, {-0.13707737058449998`, 
     0.33206331204543804`}}, {{-0.15739809597472298`, 
     0.296918061589936`}, {-0.152964624886857`, 
     0.29613490529095704`}}, {{-0.1658208075617013`, 
     0.33373440309693436`}, {-0.16666965910887294`, 
     0.3330881939930908`}}, {{-0.022940760033693074`, 
     0.32789850079501953`}, {-0.023064724202343147`, 
     0.3281278854334021`}}, {{-0.1738491209870721`, 
     0.3215289918789799`}, {-0.17359189280402723`, 
     0.3225643511484479`}}, {{-0.0950261039467197`, 
     0.334595349742704`}, {-0.027108449688450102`, 
     0.330628317267724`}}, {{-0.0616606278931308`, 
     0.29819810751174`}, {-0.0461571438273879`, 
     0.297914496015335`}}, {{-0.14462682853728`, 
     0.33103518527674103`}, {-0.147200993609053`, 
     0.330628833209078`}}, {{-0.1615835847589727`, 
     0.30781445643486477`}, {-0.16205643779747447`, 
     0.3082302959231285`}}, {{-0.17429348925235025`, 
     0.31836240577202296`}, {-0.17433116928861334`, 
     0.31729623722536016`}}, {{-0.16592100502526022`, 
     0.31658848416191104`}, {-0.1658777375327947`, 
     0.3159602800548601`}}, {{-0.1658208075617013`, 
     0.33373440309693436`}, {-0.16493948767647237`, 
     0.3343355772937574`}}, {{-0.00002719377097363207`, 
     0.3196359442287738`}, {3.6948222259525213`*^-16, 
     0.31859334586997`}}, {{-0.16205643779747447`, 
     0.3082302959231285`}, {-0.16250701729045952`, 
     0.30867017158342486`}}, {{-0.16435722154391225`, 
     0.2995137321320412`}, {-0.1652581479252421`, 
     0.30008510487417167`}}, {{-0.024446071569157422`, 
     0.32967096730193374`}, {-0.024239788467129365`, 
     0.3295114940776837`}}, {{-0.16580184752261332`, 
     0.31533517751737167`}, {-0.1658777375327947`, 
     0.3159602800548601`}}, {{-0.0032019104828343607`, 
     0.32944803096781144`}, {-0.002658896809373818`, 
     0.3285575889487024`}}, {{-0.121121195673471`, 
     0.333545953703752`}, {-0.12738864504220201`, 
     0.333056034103054`}}, {{-0.15893195007983538`, 
     0.30613277432504504`}, {-0.158354208447265`, 
     0.30588232057279774`}}, {{-0.16394119730653092`, 
     0.3237549736620164`}, {-0.164273433498032`, 
     0.3232200609690685`}}, {{-0.16038815001632004`, 
     0.3272754550920334`}, {-0.15985020089541102`, 
     0.3276027519287627`}}, {{-0.15739809597472298`, 
     0.296918061589936`}, {-0.15844348057804805`, 
     0.29713091408852776`}}, {{-0.022569038450355353`, 
     0.32692593695745403`}, {-0.02250840573536552`, 
     0.3266723465370751`}}, {{-0.14213853479564478`, 
     0.30300164707850935`}, {-0.13271344733787804`, 
     0.3020833144302151`}}, {{-0.1559368895484579`, 
     0.30518999460343643`}, {-0.1565539214362742`, 
     0.3053156294928492`}}, {{-0.025934928004331545`, 
     0.2979100015567508`}, {-0.025693428401407696`, 
     0.2979907956012883`}}, {{-0.022642808371541714`, 
     0.32717602179538546`}, {-0.022569038450355353`, 
     0.32692593695745403`}}, {{-0.15776421977096358`, 
     0.30566226185823286`}, {-0.1571635818780663`, 
     0.3054731941517472`}}, {{-0.09453629942331661`, 
     0.342981057317432`}, {-0.09711594348365293`, 
     0.3430650032516095`}}, {{-0.15755062552794172`, 
     0.3286199534995984`}, {-0.1581446064921331`, 
     0.3284109102260923`}}, {{-0.145936615236459`, 
     0.339332441377564`}, {-0.148510780308232`, 
     0.338926089309901`}}, {{-0.17305364983193894`, 
     0.3099794839639255`}, {-0.1733983396816671`, 
     0.310989099763386`}}, {{-0.022425923072385`, 
     0.3021820550043753`}, {-0.022406484973584426`, 
     0.3024359681709503`}}, {{-0.02511076646419278`, 
     0.3300819804336035`}, {-0.025345604714332153`, 
     0.33019527396257353`}}, {{-0.00992861401320636`, 
     0.33587244261444776`}, {-0.010843065856772359`, 
     0.336373968949508`}}, {{-0.00043362294146330525`, 
     0.3227354333633945`}, {-0.0006761538014226468`, 
     0.32374979504491025`}}, {{-0.1615835847589727`, 
     0.30781445643486477`}, {-0.16108973877142355`, 
     0.30742377930909276`}}};
```

Looks random:

```
Graphics[Table[{Hue[i/Length[randomLines]], 
   Arrow@randomLines[[i]]}, {i, Length[randomLines]}] ]
```

[image: Unsorted real world data]

Sort into paths:

```
sorted = mySort[randomLines];
```

This is what I expect:

```
Graphics[{
  Arrowheads[.02],
  Table[{PointSize[0.015], Hue[i/Length[sorted]], 
    Point[sorted[[i, 1, 1]]], Arrow@sorted[[i]], GrayLevel[0], 
    Text[i, sorted[[i, 1, 1]], {0, 0}]}, {i, Length[sorted]}]
  }]
```

[image: Sorted real world data]

Comment: I think you can get this working MUCH better using Nearest[randomLines] to get a NearestFunction. Then use DataStructure with a "DynamicArray", "LinkedList", or "DoublyLinkedList" to collect the segments of each spiral. I can't write it for you because my version is too old (Doesn't have DataStructure).

Comment: Other potentially useful resources are [FindShortestTour](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindShortestTour.html) and this [very similar question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/136181/46490).

Comment: Also, define randomLines using: randomLines=CreateDataStructure["HashSet"'] and "Insert" each segment to randomLines. Then each time you "Append" a segment to a spiral, you "Remove" the segment from randomLines. In some cases it could be tricky make the spirals correctly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this should do the trick and also should have decent performance:

```
TOL = 0.5 Sqrt[Min[Total[(randomLines[[All, 1]] - randomLines[[All, 2]])^2, {2}]]];
(*pts=DeleteDuplicates[Flatten[randomLines,1],Norm[#1-#2] <TOL&];*)

pts = Flatten[randomLines, 1];
clusters = DeleteDuplicates[Sort /@ Nearest[pts -> "Index", pts, {\[Infinity], TOL}]];
pts = pts[[clusters[[All, 1]]]];

edges = Partition[Flatten[Nearest[pts -> "Index", Flatten[randomLines, 1], {\[Infinity], TOL}]], 2];
A = KirchhoffMatrix[edges];
chains = Table[
  Module[{L, cycles, perm},
   L = A[[c, c]];
   cycles = SparseArray`HamiltonianCycle[L];
   If[Length[cycles] == 0,
    perm = SparseArray`MinimumBandwidthOrdering[L][[2, 1]];
    ,
    perm = cycles[[1]];
    ];
   pts[[c[[perm]]]]
   ],
  {c, SparseArray`StronglyConnectedComponents[A]}];

Graphics[Table[{RandomColor[], Arrow[c]}, {c, chains}]]
```

For the synthetic example, we obtain the following:

[image]

For the real world example, we get:

[image]

This is how this works:

- First we determine the smallest edge length in order to determine a reasonable tolerance parameter `TOL`. We assume from here on that the distance between points that are to be identified with each other aare considerably smaller than this minimal edge length.
- We use <s>`DeleteDuplicates`</s> `Nearest` to perform the actual identification with respect to this tolerance parameter.
- We determine the edges `edges` of the underlying graph (again using the tolerance `TOL`).
- We build the graph Laplacian `A` of the underlying graph (omitting the creation of  `Graph` data structure for performance reasons - as usual).
- Then we go through the connected compontents and consider each component's graph Laplacian `L` separately. If we find a Hamiltonian cycle, we use it as reordering of that component. Otherwise, the connected component `c` is a linear chain. In that case, we use the minimum bandwidth reordering.
  This works because a linear chain must have a reordering of vertices that brings the Laplacian into tridiagonal form. And the graph Laplacian can be tridiagonal only if the indices of neighboring vertices differ by $\pm 1$. So any one of the two possible minimal bandwidth reorderings for `c` will do.

Comment: Henrik, this is awesome! Your algorithm sorts my ~10000 lines in 0.11 seconds, compared to my clumsy approach using 369 seconds. More than 3000 times faster!
The algorithmic complexity is also excellent, I haven't checked in detail, but it seems to be O[n] or even better.

Comment: I am glad to see you happy! =D

Comment: The complexity of the ordering operations is probably indeed O(n). However, we use ˋNearestˋ to identify end points. It involves a space partition tree and thus have complexity O(n log(n)).