# Group a list of pairs based on the path they make

Tags: list-manipulation, gathering

I have a list of pairs of numbers and I want to group these pairs in such a way that in each group, the second element of each item is equal to the first element of the next one. For example, consider this list:

```
list = {{-1, -2}, {-1, 1.4}, {-2, -2.24}, {-3, -4}, {-5, -6}, {-5, -5.08}, {-6, 1},
{1, 1.4}, {1, 2}, {-2.24, -3.16}, {-3.16, -3.6}, {-4.12, -5.08}, {-4.12, -4.48},
{2.24, 2.84}, {2.24, 3.16}, {2.84, 3.6}, {-3.6, -4.48}, {-5.4, -6.32}, {-5.4, -5.84},
{-6.32, -6.72}, {3.16, 3.6}, {4.24, -5}, {-5.84, -6.72}};
```

which can be divided into 12 groups like this:

```
{{ {-1, -2}, {-2, -2.24}, {-2.24, -3.16}, {-3.16, -3.6}, {-3.6, -4.48} },
 { {-1, 1.4} },
 { {-3, -4} },
 { {-5, -6}, {-6, 1}, {1, 1.4} },
 { {4.24, -5}, {-5, -5.08} },
 { {1, 2} },
 { {-4.12, -5.08} },
 { {-4.12, -4.48} },
 { {2.24, 2.84}, {2.84, 3.6} },
 { {2.24, 3.16}, {3.16, 3.6} },
 { {-5.4, -6.32}, {-6.32, -6.72} },
 { {-5.4, -5.84}, {-5.84, -6.72} }}
```

My current approach involves looping through all elements and removing each one from the main list after `Append`ing it to its designated group, which is a highly inefficient and dirty code. Considering that the list might become too big, is there a fast and efficient way to do this in *Mathematica*?

Comment: Why isn't `{{4.24, -5}, {-5, -5.08}}` and `{{4.24, -5}, {-5, -6}, {-6, 1}, {1, 1.4}}` in your list?

Comment: @CarlWoll good point! seems my code has a bug too

Comment: Maybe this is an answer to your question: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/258537

Answer (score 6):

Maybe you can take advantage of [`Graph`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graph) functionality:

```
findPaths[l_] := With[{g = Graph[DirectedEdge @@@ l]},
    Flatten[
        Outer[
            FindPath[g, ##, Infinity, All]&, 
            Pick[VertexList[g], VertexInDegree[g], 0],
            Pick[VertexList[g], VertexOutDegree[g], 0]
        ],
        2
    ]
]
```

Then:

```
findPaths[list]
```

> {{-1, 1.4}, {-1, -2, -2.24, -3.16, -3.6, -4.48}, {-3, -4}, {-4.12, -5.08}, {-4.12, -4.48}, {2.24, 3.16, 3.6}, {2.24, 2.84,
> 3.6}, {-5.4, -5.84, -6.72}, {-5.4, -6.32, -6.72}, {4.24, -5, -6, 1,
> 1.4}, {4.24, -5, -5.08}, {4.24, -5, -6, 1, 2}}

Comment: This is more or less what I am looking for. But there is one group missing: `{{2.24, 3.16}, {3.16, 3.6}}`

Comment: @polfosol Fixed

Comment: Thanks. I am not trying to be difficult here, but why does `{1, 1.4}` has a separate group while being included in another one? Edit: got it. my mistake

Answer (score 4):

Another method, which may or may not qualify as "dirty code":

```
Most@NestWhileList[
    Function[i, 
     SelectFirst[
      list, (i[[2]] == #[[1]] &)]], #, (! MissingQ[#] &)] & /@ list
```

which gives:

```
{{-1,-2},{-2,-2.24},{-2.24,-3.16},{-3.16,-3.6},{-3.6,-4.48}}
{{-1,1.4}}
{{-2,-2.24},{-2.24,-3.16},{-3.16,-3.6},{-3.6,-4.48}}
{{-3,-4}}
{{-5,-6},{-6,1},{1,1.4}}
{{-5,-5.08}}
{{-6,1},{1,1.4}}
{{1,1.4}}
{{1,2}}
{{-2.24,-3.16},{-3.16,-3.6},{-3.6,-4.48}}
{{-3.16,-3.6},{-3.6,-4.48}}
{{-4.12,-5.08}}
{{-4.12,-4.48}}
{{2.24,2.84},{2.84,3.6}}
{{2.24,3.16},{3.16,3.6}}
{{2.84,3.6}}
{{-3.6,-4.48}}
{{-5.4,-6.32},{-6.32,-6.72}}
{{-5.4,-5.84},{-5.84,-6.72}}
{{-6.32,-6.72}}
{{3.16,3.6}}
{{4.24,-5},{-5,-6},{-6,1},{1,1.4}}
{{-5.84,-6.72}}
```

Comment: Why so many groups?!

Comment: If you don't want the duplicate subpaths you can use: `DeleteDuplicates[paths, ContainsAll]` where `paths` is the result above.

Comment: This approach certainly doesn't increase efficiency for big lists

Comment: Yeah probably not.

Answer (score 4):

For some speed-up for large input list, instead of using `FindPath` on *all* pairs of source and sink nodes in graph `g`, we can take pairs `{v1,v2}` where `v1` is a source vertex in graph `g` and `v2` is a sink node which is a descendant of `v1`:

```
ClearAll[allPaths]
allPaths[l_] := Module[{g = Graph[DirectedEdge @@@ l], sources, sinks, pairs},
  sources = GraphComputation`SourceVertexList @ g;
  sinks = GraphComputation`SinkVertexList @ g;
  pairs = Join @@ 
     (Thread[{#, Intersection[sinks, VertexOutComponent[g, #]]}] & /@ sources);
  Join @@ (FindPath[g, ##, ∞, All] & @@@ pairs)]
```

**Examples:**

```
Sort[allPaths[list]] // Column
```

[image]

```
SeedRandom[1]
list2 = DeleteCases[{a_, a_}] @ DeleteDuplicatesBy[Sort] @ RandomInteger[1000, {500, 2}];

allPaths[list2]; // RepeatedTiming // First
```

> ```
> 0.015
> ```

versus `findPaths` from Carl Woll's answer:

```
findPaths[list2]; // RepeatedTiming // First
```

> ```
> 0.53
> ```

```
Sort @ allPaths[list2] == Sort @ findPaths[list2]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Answer (score 1):

I did a benchmark to compare my own (improved) method with the ones proposed by [kglr](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/125) and [Carl Woll](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/45431). My initial thought was to treat this problem in a procedural, old-fashioned way. Here is the code:

<sub>**Edited later**: Using some simple tricks, I managed to double-up the speed. These lines are from the last edition:</sub>

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
merge = Which[# == {} || #2 == {}, 0,
    Last@# == #2[[1]], {{}, #~Join~Rest@#2},
    #[[1]] == Last@#2, {{}, #2~Join~Rest@#},
    True, 0] &;

pathsFind[li_List] := Module[{a = li, q},
   Do[
    Do[If[ListQ[q = merge @@ a[[{i, j}]]], a[[{i, j}]] = q],
     {j, 2, Length@a}, {i, 1, j - 1}];
    If[FreeQ[a, {}], Break[], a = a~DeleteCases~{}],
    Length@a];
   a];
```

Nothing fancy. It just loops through the elements multiple times until all paths are found. This code compares `allPaths` by kglr, `findPaths` by Carl Woll and `pathsFind`:

```
Module[{li, p, rand},
 li = DeleteCases[{a_, a_}]@DeleteDuplicatesBy[Sort]@RandomInteger[1000, {500, 2}];
 First /@ {
   RepeatedTiming[p = findPaths@li;],
   {Length@p},
   RepeatedTiming[p = allPaths@li;],
   {Length@p},
   RepeatedTiming[p = pathsFind@li;],
   {Length@p}
   }]
```

The result is `{0.298115, 362, 0.0115792, 362, 0.907272, 332}`. Obviously, `allPaths` is faster by an order of magnitude. But it seems both faster methods are not so accurate and miss some paths along the way, since the number of groups in the last method is less than the other two. Regarding kglr's comment, I still think lower number of groups means higher accuracy and can't understand what is wrong with my code aside from being slow.

By the way, I appreciate all the efforts and nice ideas proposed here, but I think it's better to stick to my own method for now.

Comment: re _" both faster methods are not so accurate and miss some paths"_, looks like the opposite is true: consider `l1 = {{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {4, 2}}; {findPaths@l1, allPaths@l1, pathsFind@l1}`. Also check  the paths in `Complement[allPaths @ li, pathsFind @ li]`(these are legitimate paths in `li`), and  the paths in `Complement[pathsFind @ li, allPaths@ li]` (these can be extended to longer paths).